# sudo texhash "directory not writable"

Tags: texstudio

I'm new in linux and the last week installed Linux Mint. For Latex installed "TeXstudio (fluthub)", then I used:

sudo cp -R texmf/* /usr/share/texmf

to copy the folder "texmf" in "/usr/share/texmf". The problem happened when I have to use "sudo texhash" on the terminal, the following error appeared:

[image: Image_from_terminal]

I tried to modify the permission of the folder "texmf", but nothing happen.

Sorry about my english.

Comment: Welcome between the users of TeX.SE.

Comment: `apt install sudo` or `apt-get install sudo` and give the commands again

Comment: @Dante Doing `sudo cp -R texmf/* /usr/share/texmf` was a bad idea. If you succeeded in doing it, your `/usr/share/texmf` is now broken, and there is no automated way to repair it. On Debian-derived systems (which Linux Mint certainly is), **everything in `/usr` except `/usr/local` is the reserved domain of the package manager** (`dpkg`, and on top of it `apt` and friends). You should copy your files either to `/usr/local/share/texmf` for multi-user installation (requires `root` or `staff` privileges) or to `~/texmf` for single-user installation (no special privileges required).

Comment: Thanks @frougon, I copied to "/usr/local/share/texmf" and now its working. If any time come to Brazil I'll pay you the first beer.